# What is the difference between the tags [synthesis] and [total-synthesis]?

Tags: discussion, tags

> [synthesis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synthesis): Synthesis is a purposeful execution of chemical reactions to obtain the desired product. Applies to long and complex natural product syntheses as much as to short one or two-step syntheses. This also covers synthetic problem sets and retrosynthetic analyses. (721 questions as of writing this post)

> [total-synthesis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/total-synthesis): Questions involving the synthesis of a natural product or complex drug/molecule pertaining to the individual steps involved or the overall scheme of the reaction (ex. question regarding the individual steps of Woodward's synthesis of vitamin B12). (6 questions as of writing this post)

What is the difference between the two? It looks like [total-synthesis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/total-synthesis) is a subset of [synthesis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synthesis) but is it required and that it should have its own tag? I get that [total-synthesis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/total-synthesis) is only applicable to synthesis of drugs or large macromolecules, however I saw 4 out of 6 questions tagged both [synthesis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synthesis) and [total-synthesis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/total-synthesis). So this tag looks a little redundant to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say that there is no functional difference between the *tags*. As for the concepts, formally, total synthesis is only a subset of synthesis, as the first two sentences of [its Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_synthesis) explain:

> Total synthesis [...] usually refers to a process not involving the aid of biological processes, which distinguishes it from semisynthesis.

Given the above, as well as the number of questions on the tags, I think it is an uncontroversial decision to merge [total-synthesis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/total-synthesis) into [synthesis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synthesis). So, I have done exactly that. Thanks for bringing it up!